# ajax file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, upload

I am struggling to get a file uploaded, processed and displayed without reloading the page. What do I use for jquery to get the file posted to the server properly?

```
 <html>

 <body>

 <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadform">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
  <br />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" />
  </form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: @guanome : I assure you he does have tried!

Comment: Yes i can get it uploaded with the php script. But running the php through a jquery method to get a response and replace like $(#response).html(response) is not working. it looks like the file is never uploaded, i just get errors on the $_FILE array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by putting the upload form in an `iframe` and communicating between the main window and the frame with javascript. It's ugly but it's the only way to do it in some browsers.

[jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) is an awesome plugin that incorporates async XHR uploads and falls back on an `iframe` for browsers that are not capable. It also supports drag and drop (for capable browsers) out of the box. It's not the simplest plug-in in the world to use, but well worth the effort, it covers all the bases.

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla HTML, it is impossible to upload a file over an AJAX request. Take a look at something along the lines of [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/). You can upload multiple files, specify wildcard filters for file section, and have the ability to display progress bars and other status information during the upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a form containing INPUT[type="file"] without reloading the page by using 
jquery.upload.js. In the $.Deferred.done handler you can add your own code to display the server response.

```
$.upload( form.action, new FormData( myForm))
.progress( function( progressEvent, upload) {
    if( progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
        var percent = Math.round( progressEvent.loaded * 100 / progressEvent.total) + '%';
        if( upload) {
            console.log( percent + ' uploaded');
        } else {
            console.log( percent + ' downloaded');
        }
    }
})
.done( function( data) {
    console.log( 'Finished upload');

    // add your code for rendering the server response
    // into html here
});
```

You can get it here : https://github.com/lgersman/jquery.orangevolt-ampere/blob/master/public/lib/ampere/jquery.upload.js