# Upload multiple files using HTML,jQuery & Webservice - not PHP

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, file-upload

I've seen lots of examples out there but none that quite tick all the boxes for me

I need a multi file uploader with a progress bar invoking a webservice to upload to a server / save details to a DB

Any examples/demos would be great

Can it even be done ?

I'm trying to use this example

http://jquery-with-asp.net/2012/02/ajax-file-upload-with-asp-net-using-valums-script/

function createUploader(){

```
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('dvFileUploader'),
            action: 'ws/FilesUploader.html',
            debug: true
        });             
    }
```

Comment: just google jqueryajax file upload ... u will find it


http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: another best one u can get  with jquery ui.. file upload...

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/6541436/782145

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the valum example , can I call the web service from the action tag of the uploader ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will helps you
[Upload Multiple Files in ASP.NET using jQuery](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=317)